# Поиск элементов в списке которые в себе имеют определенный знак

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Например у меня есть :

```
a = '1'
```

Как мне найти все элементы в списке

```
lst = ['123' , '231' , '564']
```

которые имеют в себе знак

```
'1'
```

Comment: В лоб - пройти по списку и проверить для каждого элемента есть знак или нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = '1'
lst = ['123' , '231' , '564']
tmp = [item for item in lst if item.find(a) != -1]

print(tmp)
```

Результат `['123', '231']`

Comment: лучше использовать `a in item` (работает для любой коллекции), вместо `item.find(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[item for item in lst if a in item]
# or
filter(lambda item: a in item, lst)
```

Comment: если вам приходится `lambda` использовать, то скорее всего вместо `filter()` следует явный genexp использовать (обратите внимание `filter()` не возвращает список здесь).